# App Engine - Intermittent 500 errors on /_ah/openid_verify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, openid

I'm getting intermittent errors when logging into my app with the Google openid.

The link they are sent to is `http://www.example.com/_ah/login_redir?claimid=www.google.com/accounts/o8/id&continue=http://www.example.com/login2?returl%253Dhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.example.com%25252Ftest-list-8`.

Then when they grant access to my app, sometimes there is a 500 error on the url: `http://www.example.com/_ah/openid_verify?continue=http://www.example.com/login2?returl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.example.com%252Ftest-list-8%2523additem&gx.rp_st=AEp4C1sATcZr10BWADPx0hXZOeG49Vdr6GjYqvx83JXTTXjEFdqS8KaHIfZD3wmwTNl-wu8r7DMwoQMvWLpqgoV8RtAUigMMjw&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=id_res&openid.op_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fud&openid.response_nonce=2011-12-06T20%3A00%3A53ZGU1ZOot7AJ4DGg&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F_ah%2Fopenid_verify%3Fcontinue%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Flogin2%3Freturl%253Dhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.example.com%25252Ftest-list-8%252523additem%26gx.rp_st%3DAEp4C1sATcZr10BWADPx0hXZOeG49Vdr6GjYqvx83JXTTXjEFdqS8KaHIfZD3wmwTNl-wu8r7DMwoQMvWLpqgoV8RtAUigMMjw&openid.assoc_handle=AMlYA9W4FErBlE7i17Z-YVirs2a0eP_LEjoDRJDVgEq9FhOSKt8xq4HT&openid.signed=op_endpoint%2Cclaimed_id%2Cidentity%2Creturn_to%2Cresponse_nonce%2Cassoc_handle%2Cns.ext1%2Cext1.mode%2Cext1.type.attr0%2Cext1.value.attr0%2Cext1.type.auto2%2Cext1.value.auto2&openid.sig=b7TBbUBO0mgF26qCpAjkS0AYeX8%3D&openid.identity=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawkBkv0HezgbtJVspVv8hxIBizNbHP_4t_M&openid.claimed_id=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawkBkv0HezgbtJVspVv8hxIBizNbHP_4t_M&openid.ns.ext1=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fsrv%2Fax%2F1.0&openid.ext1.mode=fetch_response&openid.ext1.type.attr0=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2Fcontact%2Femail&openid.ext1.value.attr0=myemail%40gmail.com&openid.ext1.type.auto2=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fapi%2Ffederated-login%2Fid&openid.ext1.value.auto2=105848731220363187343`

The 500 error doesn't even show up in my logs. It seems to happen for about 5-10% of logins.

Comment: Happened to me too, I suppose that could be the reason why federated identity is marked experimental. I'm trying with Spring Security...

Comment: would advise to use better Google Identity Toolkit: http://code.google.com/apis/identitytoolkit/

Comment: @PéterVarga Nope, no quota denials.

Comment: me too. works with google and yahoo, but not stackexchange.

Answer (score 2):

For Error 500 means - Page not Found / ID / Password missing

For the same you need to check again with openID or just make one Google ID for the same testing purpose only

Answer (score 1):

In your service() method, capture and output the exception by wrapping your doGet() as in:

```
.
.
.
try {
    doGet(request,response);
} catch (Throwable e) {
    writer.println("<pre>");
    e.printStackTrace(writer);
    writer.println("</pre>");
}
.
.
.
```

Comment: I have similar error, and as far as I know, the request never even enter my app, and thus not log-able from our side.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21083255/1615845

Defect here:
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3589