# Intermittent "500 Server Error" on "/_ah/openid_verify" using AppEngine Federated / OpenID login

Tags: google-app-engine

I am getting this error about 20% of the time. I've dumped and compared traffic on successful and failed requests and there is no noticeable difference:

[image]

There's nothing in the AppEngine logs or dashboard, and also no way to catch exceptions on requests that hit "/_ah" URLs. I've attached a script that tries the login every 5 minutes, as well as the traffic dumps for successful and failed requests.

I would really appreciate it if someone from Google could take a look at this. The error definitely occurs deep in the bowls of the AppEngine OpenID implementation and there is no way for an outsider to see such errors.

Thanks,
Graeme

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6618078/AppEngine%20OpenID%20error/error.dump
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6618078/AppEngine%20OpenID%20error/success.dump
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6618078/AppEngine%20OpenID%20error/test.sh

Comment: Did you check the online logs from the application's dashboard for what exactly went wrong?

Comment: "There's nothing in the AppEngine logs or dashboard"

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to this bug that is only **3.5 years old and not fixed** as they don't consider it a "production issue".

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3589

The bug is about non-gmail accounts but I have the same server error with gmail accounts (started today for me, 01/12/2014).

No error acknowledged here https://code.google.com/status/appengine.